# UITabBarController initially highlights all tab bar item images

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm programmatically instantiating a `UITabBarController` that will manage 2 view controllers, and then setting it as the `rootViewController`. However when the views appear, it highlights all the tab item's images (although the text is properly highlighted). No matter what I set to the `selectedIndex` the images will all appear highlighted. Only when you tap on the tab bar items does it actually toggle the highlighted state on the images. What's going on here?

Code:

```
UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [self storyboard];
OGVideoStreamViewController *questionsController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OGVideoStreamViewController"];
questionsController.isQuestion = YES;
OGVideoStreamViewController *answersController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OGVideoStreamViewController"];
answersController.isQuestion = NO;
OGMatchesViewController *matchesController = [[OGMatchesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OGMatchesViewController" bundle:nil];

questionsController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Questions" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab Icon - Questions"] tag:0];
answersController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Answers" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab Icon - Answers"] tag:1];
matchesController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Inbox" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Tab Icon - Inbox"] tag:2];

[tabController setViewControllers:@[questionsController, answersController, matchesController] animated:NO];
tabController.selectedViewController = questionsController;


[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow].rootViewController = tabController;
```

[image]

Comment: Tip of the Day - *Don't kitchen sink the AppDelegate*

Comment: This code isn't in the App Delegate. This code is in another view controller, which gets triggered after a user logs in.

Comment: Cool. You can try debugging it and see the *event(s)* when the tab bar items become highlighted. I was also interested in setting those 3 images for different control states - ```forState:UIControlStateNormal``` etc. Its an interesting puzzle to solve. Starred it, don't hesitate to share the fix if you solve it yourself.

Comment: What do you mean by events? The only method from `UITabBarControllerDelegate` that I can think of is `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` but I'm confident it's selecting the correct VC (I've tried calling `[UITabbarController setSelectedViewController:]` and `[UITabbarController setSelectedIndex:]`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same problem and it was due to me calling:

```
[UIView appearance].tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000
                        green:0.793
                         blue:0.236
                        alpha:1.000];
```

I called it in my AppDelegate, so i could change it to the following:

```
self.window.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.000
                    green:0.793
                     blue:0.236
                    alpha:1.000];
```